# Why without setting object privileges to oracle we can insert/select?

Tags: oracle, object, privileges

I can select, insert into table without specifying privilege, why?

1. create user test_a
2. grant system privileges create session
3. grant object privilege create table
4. login as test_a user
5. I can create my_job table (as expected) but also I can do insert/select of my_job as unexpected, because I do not grant select/insert privilege (commented)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are the **owner** of that table which means that you can do anything you want with it. You can perform any DML (select, insert, update, delete), but also any DDL on it - you can alter the table (add new columns, modify existing ones), truncate it or even drop it - all that without any additional privileges.

But, if you'd want to allow someone else do *stuff* on your tables, then you'd have to grant privileges to other users.

Comment: But I don't understand I am logged as sys user, creating test_a user, and provide only create table privilege. Next me connect as  test_a  user, and expect only create table, but do not insert or update. for example I can't create sequence, because I don't have privilege and its fine.

Comment: Oracle designed it that way. Owner doesn't require any additional privileges on its own tables (actually, any of its own objects, not just tables), it always has full privileges.

Comment: thank you, me just follow some tutorial video.... and now you explain missing point much better :)

Comment: @JonasBikus This is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423) feature: *For you to insert rows into a table, **the table must be in your own schema** or you must have the INSERT object privilege on the table.*

Comment: Maybe there is a way to define all privileges in user's own schema? Which includes like grant all privileges in own schema(includes  grant create table to test_a; excludes grant create any table to test_a;)

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you're talking about **roles**. So - yes, you could create a role (let's call it MY_ROLE), grant set of privileges to it (e.g. CREATE SESSION, CREATE TABLE, CREATE SEQUENCE, CREATE PROCEDURE, ...) and then just GRANT MY_ROLE TO TEST_A. Doing so, you'd easily create new users with the same set of privileges.

Comment: how to give privilege to select all tables? GRANT SELECT on all test_a.* to test_b; something like this?

Comment: You can't; you'd have to grant privileges on each table separately. If there are a lot of tables, it is a tedious job so - you can then write SQL which will write SQL for you, e.g. `select 'grant select on ' || table_name || ' to test_b;' from user_tables;` and then you'd just run bunch of statements this query returned. Or - of course - you could switch to PL/SQL and write a procedure which will do it for you (in a loop, using dynamic SQL).